# please can someone tell me why the program get stuck after entering the first element of the loop?

Tags: c, loops, structure

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#define maxlong 20  

typedef struct {
    char name[maxlong];
    char surname[maxlong];
} personne;  

//writing the code to enter persons name and surname  
//.ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff

personne enterPersonne() {
    personne r;

    printf("write the surname: ");   
    scanf("%s",&r.name);
    printf("write the name : ");
    scanf("%s",&r.surname);

    return r;   
} 

int main (void)
{
    int dimension,i;
    personne *pers;

    printf("enter the persons count : "); 
    scanf("%d",&dimension);

    for(i=0; i<dimension; i++)
        *(pers+i) = enterPersonne(); 

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: `personne *pers;` is an uninitialized variable. Where does it point? Nowhere, that's where.

Comment: but why when i write this code it works fine                                                                           int main (void)
{

personne *t;

*t = saisirPersonne();
*(t+1)= saisirPersonne();
*(t+2)= saisirPersonne();   return 0; }

Comment: Undefined behavior can work sometimes, and other times it won't. It's undefined. Undefined doesn't mean "will always crash".

Comment: @enienieni the fact that you observe the "expected" behavior doesn't mean that the program is actually correct. That is just a coincidence that part of your expectations met.

Comment: Is this a C or C++ program you're writing? It looks like C, but you had both tags originally, I want to make sure it is C before I make a suggestion. The answer depends on which language you're using.

Comment: it's C not C++ , sorry for the wrong tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the `for` loop in `main`, you need to allocate a memory buffer to hold the contents of the `pers` array.

A conventional way would to do this would be:

```c
    pers = (personne *)malloc(dimension * sizeof(personne));
    if ( pers == NULL ) {
        // add code here to handle an out-of-memory condition
    }
```